# sap.uxap.ObjectPageLayout jumping buttons due to scrollbar

Tags: sapui5, scrollbar

Example:
https://plnkr.co/edit/213BfJ4Q0shqBqaK
If there is no scollbar at the 2nd section for you, you might have a bigger screen than me and need to add a few more buttons.

If you set the `useIconTabBar` property of the `ObjectPageLayout`  to `true` and have a section that needs scrolling but another that does not, the minimaize and pin button of the `ObjectPageLayout` Header are displaced each time you navigate between sections.

The scroll bar is across both header and content forcing the header to reajust its center, making the buttons move. This reajustment looks out of place in the otherwise static behavior of the header.

Is there a way to restrict the scrolling to just the content area of the ObjectPageLayout or fix the horizontal position of those buttons?
If there is a need to navigate often between the Sections the displacement can be very irretatiing for an enduser.

Comment: You could perform instant programmatic scrolling to the top of the page on tab switch. You can enhance this by check and do it only if needed. Users wont notice this automatic scrolling. Solution relies on additional JS tho.

Comment: what do you mean by "instant programmatic scrolling"? Do you want me to place the ObjectPageLayout  inside a scroll container? not sure i understand

Comment: Not sure if this is actually irritating, but have you tried adding a ScrollContainer?

Comment: @Erch you can [programmatically scroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) to a web element (DOM ref).  There is also a jq plugin for scrolling if you decide.

Comment: @Marc i added one in the large section, but the scrollbar still apears at the header, i updated the plnkr aswell

Comment: @fmi21i am trying to stay within the framework to reduce the risk of smth not working after updates

Comment: When using a fixed value (e.g. 30rem) instead of a relative value (100%) it works as expected. Not sure if this is a good approach...